# How to generate bootstrap alert from FileSystemWatcher

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have an Asp.Net Razor Page that uses a FileSystemWatcher to generate an event when a new file is added to a particular directory.  It works fine and I am able to generate a console message.

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        var directoryToWatch = @"c:\\psdata\\in";

        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryToWatch))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {directoryToWatch} does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            var inputFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directoryToWatch);
            inputFileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

            inputFileWatcher.Created += FileCreated;
            inputFileWatcher.Error += WatcherError;

            inputFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    private static void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Instead of writing to console, how to raise the #btnSubmit event that will cause the bootstrap alert to be generated?
        Console.WriteLine($"* File created: {e.Name} - type: {e.ChangeType}");
    }
```

I am, however unable to figure out how to generate a bootstrap alert message that would announce the fact that a file has been created.  Here's my markup:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $('#myAlert').show('fade');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
            }, 2500);
        });

        $('#linkClose').click(function () {
            $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Data Processor</h1>

<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
    <a id="linkClose" href="#" class="close">&times</a>
    <strong>Alert! </strong>A file has just been added to the psData directory
</div>
```

Any help in figuring out how to generate the bootstrap alert when a new file is created would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use signalR to generate the bootstrap alert from the server to client.

The SignalR server library is included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage. The [JavaScript client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-signalr-client-library-1) isn't automatically included in the project. For this tutorial, you use Library Manager (LibMan) to get the client library from unpkg. unpkg is a content delivery network (CDN)) that can deliver anything found in npm, the Node.js package manager.

Create a SignalR hub that serves as a high-level pipeline that handles client-server communication.

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
{  
}
```

Configure SignalR

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Add SignalR client code

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/notificationHub")
        .build();
    connection.on("Notify", function (message) {
        appendMessage(message)
    });
    connection.start();

    function appendMessage(content) {
        alert(content);
    }

</script>
}
```

Inject an instance of IHubContext in a PageModel

```
private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;
public CreateFileModel(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
{
        _hubContext = hubContext;
}
```

Now, with access to an instance of IHubContext, you can call hub methods as if you were in the hub itself.

```
 private  void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"A file has just been added to the psData directory");

        //Console.WriteLine($"* File created: {e.Name} - type: {e.ChangeType}");
    }
```

Reference :[Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) and  [Send messages from outside a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2)